# PHP Laravel 404 not found files while in edit view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have sub-folder in views which is called "company".

Everything is working well when i try to access `127.0.0.1:8000/home` or `127.0.0.1:8000/company`, but when i try to access `127.0.0.1:8000/company/1/edit` where i should edit my company info then i got 404 Not Found error for all of css,js and other links mentioned in my layout but page works fine if i dont extend `layouts.app`. For some reason it is trying to access

> 127.0.0.1:8000/company/css

and

> 127.0.0.1:8000/comapany/js

instead of

> 127.0.0.1:8000/css

and

> 127.0.0.1:8000/js

But that is happening only for edit page.

Here is my folder sctructure:
[image]

Routes.php:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('auth/login');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::resource('company','CompanyController');
Route::resource('users','UserController');
Route::resource('roles','RoleController');
```

edit.blade.php (from company subfolder):

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <from method = 'post' action = "{{ route ('company.update', [$company->id]) }}">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" valuae = 'put'>

        <input type="text"
               id="company-name";
               required
               name = 'name'
               value = '{{ $company->name }}'>
        <input type="text"
               id="company-name";
               required
               name = 'website'
               value = '{{ $company->website }}'>

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </from>
@endsection
```

Comment: Please show us the relevant section of `routes.php`.

Comment: also the content of the company/edit layout

Comment: Make sure that the links to the js and css start with `/`, or else it's going to look in the current directory instead of the webroot.

Comment: Also necessary to see where you're calling the `js` and `css` files (so the content of `layouts/app.blade.php`). Are you using `{{ asset() }}` to link your files? Or are you including them like `<script src="file.js">`?

Comment: @TimLewis i'm using second method <script src="file.js">

Comment: @aynber This solved my problem. I just added "/" infront of all links and js files and it is working perfect! THanks mate!!!

Comment: `/` works, Laravel's (Blade's) function of `<script src="{{ asset("file.js") }}">` for example would handle that for you by using the fully qualified URL to that file, so consider using that too.

Comment: @TimLewis can you please check https://codeshare.io/timl ?

Comment: @aynber can you check https://codeshare.io/timl please? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved thanks to Aynber and Tym Lewis.

Just adding `/`infront of my src links solving this issue.

Before:

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

After(fixed):

```
<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```